# How to store/restore table with dynamic elements in view state in c# asp web aplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to concept of web app with dynamic content.
I am creating simple app that take information (steps for a test) from database and adds rows to table (every row is containing, two labels, two radio buttons and text field).

It works like this:
 1. I have a page with text box and button,
 2. I put test ID to retrieve test steps, then click submit button
 3. Based on number of steps I add a row to table for every step, so I have table that looks like this:

```
[Label.text="Step1"][RadioButtonPass][RadioButtonFail][Label.Text="Comment:"][TextBox]
[Label.text="Step2"][RadioButtonPass][RadioButtonFail][Label.Text="Comment:"][TextBox]
[Label.text="Step3"][RadioButtonPass][RadioButtonFail][Label.Text="Comment:"][TextBox]
etc.
```

4. When user press every radio button he can click submitResult button and data are send to db.

Page is genereting correctly but I am having trouble with dynamic content because when I hit submitResult button table is empty again (at this point submitResult button do nothing). I read about it and I think I need to store table into  View State. How can I do it?

I tried to save table to

```
ViewState[table.ID] = table;
```

at the end of PopulateTable method and then restore it in

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ViewState[TableForMethods.ID] != null)
                {
                    TableForMethods = (Table)ViewState[TableForMethods.ID];
                }
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work.

My code looks like this:

***.aspx**

```
<body style="height: 510px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <p>
            Put test case ID and submit
        </p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxId" runat="server">1804673290</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRetriveId" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonSubmitId_Click" Text="Submit" Width="81px" />
        <p>
            &nbsp;
        </p>
         <p>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelMethods" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Table ID="TableForMethods" runat="server">
            </asp:Table>
        </p>
        <div style="text-align: right">
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmitResults" runat="server" Text="Submit result" OnClick="ButtonSubmitResults_Click" Visible="False" />
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: right; position: absolute; bottom: 0px">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>

    </form>

    <script>
        var trPassArray = $("tr input[id*='RadioButtonPass']").click(function () {
            this.closest("tr").setAttribute("bgcolor", "yellowgreen");
            console.log("zmien na green");
            console.log(closest("tr"));
        });

        var trFailArray = $("tr input[id*='RadioButtonFail']").click(function() {
            this.closest("tr").setAttribute("bgcolor", "orangered");
            console.log("zmien na red");
            console.log(this.closest("tr"));
        });

        console.log(trPassArray);
        console.log(trFailArray);
    </script>
</body>
```

***.aspx.cs**

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void ButtonSubmitId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.PopulateTable(TableForMethods, value);
           ButtonSubmitResults.Visible = true;
        }

    protected void ButtonSubmitResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

   private void PopulateTable(Table table, string value)
        {
            string[] sep = { "<br>" };
            var words = value.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int iterator = 1; iterator <= words.Count(); iterator++)
            {
                var tRow = new TableRow { ID = "Row" + iterator };
                table.Rows.Add(tRow);

                var tCell = new TableCell();

                var myLabel = new Label
                {
                    Text = words[iterator - 1],
                    ID = "Label " + iterator
                };

                var radiobuttonPass = new RadioButton
                {
                    Text = "Pass ",
                    ID = "RadioButtonPass " + iterator,
                    GroupName = "passFailGroup" + iterator,
                };

                radiobuttonPass.CheckedChanged += passRadioButton_CheckedChanged;

                var radiobuttonFail = new RadioButton
                {
                    Text = "Fail ",
                    ID = "RadioButtonFail " + iterator,
                    GroupName = "passFailGroup" + iterator,
                };

                radiobuttonFail.CheckedChanged += failRadioButton_CheckedChanged;

                var upPassFail = new UpdatePanel { UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional };
                upPassFail.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(radiobuttonPass);
                upPassFail.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(radiobuttonFail);

                var passTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger
                {
                    ControlID = radiobuttonPass.ID,
                    EventName = "CheckedChanged"
                };
                upPassFail.Triggers.Add(passTrigger);

                var failTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger
                {
                    ControlID = radiobuttonFail.ID,
                    EventName = "CheckedChanged"
                };
                upPassFail.Triggers.Add(failTrigger);

                var labelComment = new Label
                {
                    Text = " Comment:",
                    ID = "LabelComment " + iterator.ToString()
                };

                TextBox textBoxComment = new TextBox { ID = "TextBoxComment " + iterator.ToString() };

                tCell.Controls.Add(myLabel);
                tCell.Controls.Add(radiobuttonPass);
                tCell.Controls.Add(radiobuttonFail);
                tCell.Controls.Add(labelComment);
                tCell.Controls.Add(textBoxComment);
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't work. `ViewState` is used by the server application to store information between requests.

- During the course of page load or a postback the server modifies the state of the page or its controls
- When you post back, without some way to "remember" what was done, all of those changes would be lost. It would be like loading the page for the first time again.
- ASP.NET solves this by writing details about the controls in a form field (`ViewState`.) That way every time there's postback you're sending data back to the server telling it what the state of the page and controls are, so it can recreate it.

You're making changes to the HTML on the client. At that point the page has been rendered, including `ViewState`. It only keeps track of the *server's* changes, not anything that happens on the client. So the server will never know that those changes happened.

There are a few ways to solve this (more than two, but these are the obvious ones.)

1. Whatever changes have to happen to modify that table, do it on the server. If the user interacts with something, do a postback to the server. The server modifies the table, and assuming that `ViewState` is enabled for the table, those changes are already written to `ViewState` and persisted.
2. Avoid postbacks. If there aren't server controls then after the page loads it behaves just like a normal HTML page, and you can do whatever you want on the client.
3. This gets a little messy: store client-side changes on the client. When you update the table on the client then you could store it in `localStorage`. When the page refreshes you could then have a client script that checks `localStorage` and restores whatever client-side stuff you stored there. Think of it as just like `ViewState`, but the opposite. `ViewState` stores server-side data between roundtrips. `localStorage` stores client-side data between roundtrips. The catch is that maybe on some postback you'll completely change the table (like new data, something else) and you'll have to have a way to distinguish that so that in that scenario you don't refresh it from `localStorage`.

Mixing WebForms with client-side code can be a little frustrating. We start learning about all of these neat client-side tools, but they don't always play well with the behavior of WebForms. Client-side code wants to change things on the page. WebForms wants to refresh the whole page.

Personally I would go with option one or two if possible vs trying to cross-breed the behavior of the two.

Comment: Hi, thanks for detailed answer, option 1 looks the best. How can I do it?
I add ViewState[table.ID] = table at the end of PopulateTable method but changes are not persistent, am I doing it correctly? What is proper way to 'load ' state?